# how to get the image path in same way as item.src?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using freewall.js from http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/

The images would be dynamic. So html will have:

```
<div class="brick">
  <img src="" width="100%">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".free-wall .brick img").each(function(index, item) {
  item.src =  "images/" + (++index) + ".jpg";
});
```

The thing I want to do is to prepend a few more images to the freewall.

```
var temp = '<div class="brick"><img src="" width="100%"></div>';
$(".add-more").click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    wall.prepend(temp);
  }
  wall.fitWidth();
});
```

When the add-more button is clicked, 4 images will be prepended. the problem is how to append the image path in same way?

help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var temp = '<div class="brick"><img src="" width="100%"></div>';
$(".add-more").click(function () {
    var start = $(".free-wall .brick img").length + 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        $(temp).prependTo(wall).find('img').attr('src', "images/" + (start + i) + ".jpg")
        //or wall.prepend('<div class="brick"><img src="images/' + (start + i) + '.jpg" width="100%"></div>');
    }
    wall.fitWidth();
});
```

---

Update:

```
$(".add-more").click(function () {
    var start = $("#freewall .brick img").length + 1,
        $imgs = $(),
        $img, loadcounter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
        $img = $(temp).appendTo('.free-wall').find('img').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/64&text=' + (start + i) + '.jpg').hide();
        $imgs = $imgs.add($img);
    }
    $imgs.on('load error', function () {
        loadcounter++;
        if (loadcounter == 4) {
            $imgs.show();
            wall.fitWidth();
        }
    }).filter(function(){
        return this.complete
    }).trigger('load')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SgtqS/)

Comment: i will try this, but the problem is if the images are already displayed in first place upon load, then click button to prepend, it shouldn't show the same images as the first loaded images? hmm

Comment: it seems to be working well, but may i ask why when prepend, images appear at top behind the firstly loaded images? Also, why images start from 18, 17, 16 and 15? Shouldn't it start from 15, 16, 17, 18?

Comment: @kittymeows where do want to add the images at the start of the wall or at the end

Comment: because there will be more than 10 dynamic images, i do not want the user to scroll down and see the new images? it would be better if the images appear at top first?

Comment: @kittymeows it is because of the prepend the last added item will be at the top

Comment: oh so if use append, it will start from first added item? Also any idea why prepended images shows (hidden) behind the loaded images?

Comment: try to change the loop to `for (var i = 3; i >=0; i--) {`

Comment: change loop already and it shows correct number, but still hiding behind the first loaded images :(

Comment: @kittymeows also I haven't used the `fitWidth()` plugin so not sure about its functionality

Comment: Also when I try to change to append, click do nothing. why is that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45242/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-kittymeows)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(".add-more").click(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
       src="images/"+(i+1)+".jpg";
       wall.prepend('<div class="brick"><img src="'+src+'" width="100%"></div>');
    }
    wall.fitWidth();
});
```

Comment: i will try this, but the problem is if the images are already displayed in first place upon load, then click button to prepend, it shouldn't show the same images as the first loaded images? hmm